# Postfix evaluation method in Java

Tags: data-structures, stack, postfix-notation

So I tried writing a code for postfix evaluation method and it is giving me the most outrageous results.

the post fix expression I entered was "92*3+4-" and by my calculation the answer should be 17. Instead I am getting 2849. What is going on?

```
 public static int postFixEvaluator(String s){
    NewStack stack=new NewStack();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
      if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) stack.push(s.charAt(i));

      else if(s.charAt(i)=='+'){
        int y=stack.pop();
        int x=stack.pop();
        int z=(int)(x+y);
        stack.push((char)(z));
        //System.out.println(z);
      }
      else if(s.charAt(i)=='-'){
        int y=stack.pop();
        int x=stack.pop();
        int z=x-y;
        stack.push((char)(z));
      }
      else if(s.charAt(i)=='*'){
        int y=stack.pop();
        int x=stack.pop();
        int z=x*y;
        stack.push((char)(z));
        System.out.println(x*y);
      }
      else if(s.charAt(i)=='/'){
        int y=stack.pop();
        int x=stack.pop();
        int z=x/y;
        stack.push((char)(z));
      }
      else if(s.charAt(i)=='%'){
        int y=stack.pop();
        int x=stack.pop();
        int z=x%y;
        stack.push((char)(z));
      }
    }
    return stack.pop();
  }




enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you're pushing characters and popping integers. That is, you have:

```
if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) stack.push(s.charAt(i));
```

So if the character is `3`, you'll push `3` on the stack.

But when you pop, you have:

```
int y=stack.pop();
```

The integer representation of the character `3` is 51.

It gets worse when you push results back onto the stack. If you have the characters 3 and 4 on the stack, you end up adding 51 and 52, and pushing 103 back onto the stack. But at some point you overflow the size of a character and things go completely off the rails.

My suggestion is that you create a stack of integers, and push integers onto the stack. So your statement above becomes:

```
if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
{
    stack.push(Character.GetNumericValue(s.charAt(i)));
}
```

And in the code for your operations, replace

```
stack.push((char)(z));
```

with

```
stack.push(z);
```